# O(n2) ,how to optimized two loop?

Tags: c++

I want to compare the elements in array whether there is a similar element is present or not?
I am using two loops and it gives TLE can anyone help me in this?
code:-

```cpp
 int main() {
    int arr=[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6]
    int max=0;
    int k;
    int c=0;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (int j= i+1;j<n;j++) {
            if (a[i]==a[j]) {
                c++;
                if (k>max) {
                    max= k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to optimize this?

Comment: This code won't even compile. It can't give TLE. To find if there are two equal elements, first use `std::sort`, then use `std::adjacent_find`, or use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: The code has undefinded behaivour. k is not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::sort` function time complexity is `nlog(n)` (According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(C%2B%2B)), it's `Intro Sort`)

So one approach for your question is to:

1. Sort the array (It's better to use `std::vector` instead of C-Style array)
2. Compare every element with the next one (Which is going to be `O(n)`)
3. If the two elements are equal, so show it or add it to a `std::set` to use it later

Here is my implementation for the algorithm that I mentioned before:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 1, 5, 4};
    std::set<int> duplicatedValues;

    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

    for (int i{0}; i < data.size()-1; ++i) 
        if (data[i] == data[i+1]) 
            duplicatedValues.insert(data[i]);

    for (int value : duplicatedValues)
        std::cout << value << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl; 
}
```

So time complexity for code above is going to be `nlog(n)`

*Note:* I should add that if you have `n` data and all of them are between range of `0` to `n-1`, We have `O(n)` for that, take a look at [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/).

***Second Approach:*** (By using `std::unordered_map`)

(It takes a little shorter time than the previous approach, but roughly 2 times more memory!)

We can add every element in a dictionary and if we had that same data again in our array, increase its number in dictionary; and finally, show elements that have number more than 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data{1, 2, 8, 2, 5, 4, 1, 9, 2, 3, 8};
    std::unordered_map<int, int> duplicatedData;

    for (int i{0}; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        if (duplicatedData.find(data[i]) == duplicatedData.end()) {
            duplicatedData[data[i]] = 1;
        }
        else {
            duplicatedData[data[i]] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (auto x : duplicatedData) {
        if (x.second > 1) {
            std::cout << x.first << " ";
        }
    } 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT:** I recorded a video for this, with performance measurement in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcReZEMB3Pg)

Comment: so with 40 hw threads on workstation we'll have one-core performance. for now i didn't watch the video to be fair

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: but compared to your version, this only scans the array once, not N times!  A parallel sort or lock-free hash table would work if you want the benefit of both, but you don't usually need it here.  Or have each thread use a private hash table for a chunk of the array, and then combine, but that takes multiple combining steps if you want the worst case (no duplicate elements) to be any better than just a single thread with a single hash table.

Answer (score -3):

i will do it like

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,5,6};
    std::atomic<bool> com_tr = false;

    std::for_each(std::execution::par, &arr[0], (&arr[0] + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)), 
    [&](auto a)
    { com_tr = std::count(&arr[0], (&arr[0] + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)), a) == 1 ? (bool)com_tr : !false; });

    if (com_tr) std::cout << "have one " << std::endl;
}
```

compiled with `c++ -std=c++17 -O3 '/home/alex/etr/b.cpp'   -o t -ltbb`

but if it's really all you need to accomplish better would be `std::any_of()`

Comment: Which is still the same `O(n^2)` time complexity, so except for running in parallel, it didn't improve at all.

Comment: you'll have a result pretty fast . say `std::nth_element( )` has O(n) and what? try to use it

Comment: Try that for an array with 1,000,000 elements. A good algorithm still handles that in a seconds. Yours keeps the CPU busy for hours.

Comment: try words from 500kb book. you'll not see seconds with any algo. That's what i did (top 15 most often words). This stuff works better than all.

Comment: 500kB book just amounts to 50-100k words, depending on the language. That's still a *tiny* data set. Scale that up by 10x, and you already start seeing the difference between `O(n log(n))` and `O(n*n)`. Another factor 10x in input size, and your algorithms performance demands increase 100x each time.

Comment: @Ext3h, especially as the optimised solution is O(n).

Comment: O(n)'s i know assume swapping elements. was 7x slower than stuff here. If it's 7x slower on 500k haha you know

Comment: This doesn't look thread-safe.  Updating `com_tr` is not an atomic RMW, so a thread could read `com_tr` as false, then another thread could store com_tr=true, then the first thread could store back the old value of com_tr=false again.  It's insane to write com_tr at all when you're not changing it, that just introduces cache-line ping-pong for no reason.  (And with seq_cst, an expensive memory barrier).  Both correctness and cache-line sharing performance problems would disappear if you did `if( count == 1) com_tr = true;` so you never store `false` and thus can't set it back.

Comment: Also, you can skip counting when `com_tr` is already true.  Still O(N^2) worst case, but makes the best case only O(N) + thread startup overhead.

Comment: it's general approach. you can't just 'stop counting' in `for_each`. that's why i've written about  `std::any_of()` .

Comment: @PeterCordes so you think machine code will be  `mov eax, com_tr   
 mov [com_tr], eax`  ?

Comment: I meant `if (!com_tr &&  std::count(...)) com_tr = true;` to skip starting new counts.  If there are more array elements than hardware threads, there should be many iterations of that parallel-for loop body left un-done when an early `count` finds a unique element.  Those iterations still run, but they do a trivial amount of work: just reading a boolean not the whole array.

Comment: And yes, writing `com_tr = ... ? com_tr : true;` will certainly do something like `movzx  eax, byte [com_tr]` / ... maybe update AL ... / `xchg [com_tr], al`.  (or `mov [com_tr], al` / `mfence` in older GCC, for the seq_cst store.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you can just add `com_tr||` to ternary condition and have short-circuit . But code here shows general approach as i said

Comment: haha now recall that say on bitcoin github not everybody knows what's short-circuit so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation